# Impossible to set a new SD card as adoptable after successfully using the first card as adoptable

Tags: sd-card, adoptable-storage

I have successfully expanded the internal storage of the phone with an sd card using the "sm partition DISK mixed" command in adb:

```
mido:/ $ sm list-disks
disk:179,96

mido:/ $ sm partition disk:179,96 mixed 50
mido:/ $ sm list-volumes
private:179,99 mounted 0e05b528-c814-4078-b7ef-1a0f95260531
private mounted null
public:179,97 mounted F227-1806
emulated mounted null
emulated:179,99 unmounted null
```

My phone is Xiaomi Redmi Note 4x MIUI Global 11.0.2 (android 7.0). Sd card used: Kingston 8GB MicroSDHC class 4.
I successfully used this mode for a while (transferred applications to sd) until I saw that class 4 memory cards are really very slow and bought a new class 10 memory card: Smartbuy microSDHC 64gb class 10.
And here, unfortunately, it was not possible to expand the internal memory with the new SD. Before using new SD card I undo adoptable storage on the 1st SD-card: "sm partition disk:xxxxx public" and also formated it using “Settings” -> “Storage” -> “SD card” -> ”ERASE SD-card". As I saw after these steps, the phone stopped distinguishing the SD card as adoptable.
Then I inserted the second SD card into the phone and started converting it into adoptable:

```
mido:/ $ sm list-disks
disk:179,64

mido:/ $ sm partition disk:179,64 mixed 75

mido:/ $ sm list-volumes
private:179,67 unmountable null
private mounted null
public:179,65 mounted C1B0-1F00
emulated mounted null
```

We see that private volume is not set, unlike it was on the 1st card. Moving applications to the sd card does not work (the "change storage" button disappeared in the interface)
I tried to

```
mido:/ $ sm format private:179,67
mido:/ $ sm mount private:179,67
Error: java.lang.IllegalStateException: command '328 volume mount private:179,67 0 -1' failed with '400 328 Command failed'
```

The "set-force-adoptable: setting also failed, but the error code changed:

```
mido:/ $ sm set-force-adoptable true
mido:/ $ sm mount private:179,67
Error: java.lang.IllegalStateException: command '336 volume mount private:179,67 0 -1' failed with '400 336 Command failed'
```

How can it be that this procedure worked with one memory card, but did not work with another? Perhaps the phone still thinks that it works with the first SD card as adoptable, but how can I reverse this?

Thank you very much in advance for your help!

Comment: @alecxs I don't know where to begin to understand how to solve it and what exactly mean "unmountable null", google just returns loads of different similar but not exact problems. Please help. I tried to `sm partition disk:179,64 private`, but result is the same (there is one unmountable null volume). `sm partition disk:179,64 private` worked without errors

Comment: no clue. is it still working with old MicroSD Card?

Comment: @alecxs Yes, it is still sucessfully working with old microSD card but doen't want to work with 2 new cards.

Comment: just for testing purposes clone working card to new one